# My HTML layout is zoomed out after compiling my laravel project with php desktop and inno installer

Tags: php, laravel, inno-setup, phpdesktop

I am new to php desktop and inno installer, and have been trying to get myself familiar with the same.
I had posted another question regarding php desktop and inno installer some few days ago, which I was able to get help. Now my program is opening after installing, but the page appears zoomed out. I don't know the reason since it works perfectly before compiling with inno installer. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
I have attached  screen shots.

[image: zoomed out image]

[image: Before compiling with inno installer]

(after and before compiling screenshots respectively)

Comment: Looks like you are missing some resources (web app css/fonts or maybe phpdesktop binary files) or paths to them are invalid. You have go to the installation directory and make sure that all files in all subdirectories are there. Then open Developer Tools popup through mouse context menu and see if all resources  in your web app (css, images and others) are loaded correctly - if not, fix paths to these resources.

Comment: I have cross checked the binary files and all my app css and fonts. They are as they are in my app before compiling it..